# Angular 6 PWA -- The PWA functionality is interefering with Azure Adal Authentication, not sure how to bypass it

Tags: angular6, service-worker, adal, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have a PWA built with Angular 6 and the @angular/pwa npm package and authenticating using adal-angular4 npm package (but could just rebuild that from scratch if needed -- the issue isn't a bug in the package I think)

When attempting to authenticate, although it does work, users are very often greeted with [this message of not found (screenshot of console but its the same).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf6xF.png)

This especially seems to be the case if you are already authenticated to another (or itself) Azure AD product. Where it normally should only load for a while and then let the user in.

Service worker error transcript:

```
Failed to load 'link.com/#LONGTOKEN' A serviceWorker passed a promise 
to FetchEvent.respondWith() that rejected with 'Error: Response not Ok 
(fetchAndCacheOnce): request for LINK.com/index.html returned response 404 Not Found'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that writing a function to check for new version of the PWA has cleaned up everything. Because it's a PWA, when replacing files with a new version -- the cache will still be there and shift+reloading won't necessarily clear it, causing a lot of unwanted behaviour.

The code for the cleanup looks like this:

First, inject in the constructor the following: `updates: SwUpdate`

`import { SwUpdate } from "@angular/service-worker"`

Then, inside ngOnInit, I have the following:

`updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      updates.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
    })`

It will force a complete refresh 2-3 seconds in if there's a new version available but all works well afterwards.